# Checking for current route in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When a webpage loads for the first time, controller of my directive needs to know what is the currently selected route.

After first load I can detect change using

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){});
```

**EDIT:**

```
Answers below are valid but it didn't work for me because:
 - I am new to AngularJS technology i didn't realize that, on our project, we are using custom route provider
 - You need to inject 'ngRoute' in your module before you can use $route
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route -> scroll down to the "Properties" section. There's literally a property called "current"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$routeChangeSuccess` callback signature
`function(event, currentRoute, previousRoute) {}`

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/1QHVuZunqd1UVlSOFx8E?p=preview)**

e.g.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
  console.log(current.$$route); // displays current $route object
});
```

The current documentation does not show the callback signatures(IDK why) but you can see them on their github, **[see this line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L384)**.

Answer (score 0):

you need to inject $route dependency in your controller and then get the current route using $route.current

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/FotjZ8pfB0OF308PGQt8?p=preview)

Controller code snippet:

```
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
   //Here setting scope with $route object
   $scope.$route = $route;
   $scope.$location = $location;
   $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
})
```